# How to insert and retrive data directly to server using .net webservice

Tags: java, android, xml

```
 <WebMethod()> _
    Public Function UpdateProductDetail(ByVal ProductName As String, ByVal Remarks As String) As Integer
        Dim sSQl As String
        Dim pobjDas As New DBAccess
        sSQl = "INSERT INTO ProductDetail (ProducDetailId, productName, Remark) VALUES (NEWID(), '" & ProductName & "', '" & Remarks & "')"
        Return pobjDas.ExecuteSQL(sSQl)
    End Function
```

This is my webservice in VB.net. How can I call It from android.

Comment: use KSOAP 2 [link](http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/)

Comment: Nice SQL injection vulnerability in your VB.net code. You should use parameters for DQL queries exposed on the net: http://www.java2s.com/Code/VB/Database-ADO.net/UseParametersinyoursqlcommand.htm

Answer (score 0):

You should provide a plattform-agnostic way to access this method. I don't know how VB.NET handles it, but I sugest using RESTful WebServices, I have a good history accessing them on Android.